# isin holidays only recognizing the first hour

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, isin, python-holidays

I have created a class with the holidays in Spain

```
class SpainBusinessCalendar(AbstractHolidayCalendar):
   rules = [
     #Spain - If one holiday is on a Sunday, each Autonomous Community can change it to a Monday.
     Holiday('Año Nuevo', month=1, day=1, observance=sunday_to_monday),
     Holiday('Epifanía del Señor', month=1, day=6, observance=sunday_to_monday),
     Holiday('Viernes Santo', month=1, day=1, offset=[Easter(), Day(-2)]),
     Holiday('Día del Trabajador', month=5, day=1, observance=sunday_to_monday),
     Holiday('Asunción de la Virgen', month=8, day=15, observance=sunday_to_monday),
     Holiday('Día de la Hispanidad', month=10, day=12, observance=sunday_to_monday),
     Holiday('Todos los Santos', month=11, day=1, observance=sunday_to_monday),
     Holiday('Día Constitución', month=12, day=6, observance=sunday_to_monday),
     Holiday('Inmaculada Concepción', month=12, day=8, observance=sunday_to_monday),        
     Holiday('Navidad', month=12, day=25, observance=sunday_to_monday)
   ]
```

Then I generated an with the size equals to the Date column in my dataframe

```
cal = SpainBusinessCalendar()
holidays = cal.holidays(start=df['Date'].min(), end=df['Date'].max())
```

Which gives the following

[image]

In order to generate a `df` column with the holidays, resulting from the values in the column `"Date"`, I have done

```
df['Feriado'] = df['Date'].isin(holidays).astype(int)
```

However, as one can guess from the image of the `holidays` output, if one is working with hourly data, which is the case, it will only pick up as holiday the first hour (with the time 00:00).

How should I proceed in order to, in the analysis of `holidays`, the hour is ignored and for a specific holiday date, assign the respective value.

---

**Edit**

Both

```
holidays = cal.holidays(start=df['Data'].dt.date.min(), end=df['Data'].dt.date.max())
```

and

```
holidays = cal.holidays(start=df['Data'].dt.floor('d').min(), end=df['Data'].dt.floor('d').max())
```

Give the same output as the image above.

Comment: Try using `df['Date'].dt.date.min()` & `df['Date'].dt.date.max()`, which will be only the date component.

Comment: @TrentonMcKinney the problem persists. The output is equal to the one in the image above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Created a column with the Date without the time component

```
df['Date_notime'] = df['Data'].dt.floor('d')
```

Then generated the holidays from that column

```
holidays = cal.holidays(start=df['Date_notime'].dt.date.min(), end=df['Date_notime'].dt.date.max())
```

And like then

```
df['Feriado'] = df['Date_notime'].isin(holidays).astype(int)
```

And at the end dropped the columns that I didn't want.